# What do call() and apply() actually do to fool methods into working on array-like objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

There's a lot of information out there of differences between call, apply and, bind but I'm struggling to find info on how exactly the call and apply methods fool existing functions—normally accepting arrays—into accepting array-like objects.

To my understanding, the full reference to such a method is an instruction on where to find the method.
The call/apply methods then change the 'this' param to point to the array-like object.

I've searched round for JS source code to no avail.

In Math.max.apply(Math,arguements), if part of the reason we can repurpose a function expecting an array to instead work on an array-like object is due to updating the 'this' param, how does it make sense to just give Math as it's context.

What is special about call and apply that tricks methods into working on array-like objects??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function multiMax(multi){
    return multi  * Math.max.apply(Math,
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));
}
assert(multiMax(3, 1, 2, 3) == 9, "3*3=9 (First arg, by  largest.)");
</script>
```

Comment: "normally accepting arrays" --- if you check the standard, you would notice that most of functions never require an object to be an array precisely. So when you say "normally" - please specify what functions exactly do that. "What is special about call and apply that tricks methods into working on array-like objects" --- nothing at all, they don't fool/trick anything.

Comment: Changing the this binding allows for the use of different prototypes through injection.

Comment: `Math.max` has nothing to do with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`call` and  `apply` can't fool functions.

Instead, when you use them to call array methods on array-like objects, that works because array methods are intentionally generic.

> The [whatever] function is intentionally generic; it does not require that
>   its `this` value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred
>   to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

In the case of `Math` functions, since they don't use the `this` value at all, you can use whatever value you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Oriol. I think more of what I'm trying to get at is, if you can pass an array-like object though call or apply to a function to be process, what are those methods doing for that processing to flow without an error that would be incurred if call or apply are not used. Example: Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1) vs arguments.slice(1). Is the difference between the two references to slice() purely that the latter doesn't find a slice method? If so, would it be possible to bind slice to arguments then call? Array.protoype.slice.bind(arguments); arguments.slice(1);

Comment: Yes, you can't call `arguments.slice` because that method does not exist on arguments object, the same way you can't use `({length:0}).slice()` but `[].slice.call({length:0})` will work. `bind` doesn't work like that, it would be `var f = [].slice.bind(arguments); f(1)` or `arguments.slice = [].slice; arguments.slice(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

All arrays are objects. The only thing that would prevent a method from working on an array-like object would involve explicitly checking if the object is an array. This is simply not done by the methods that can work on array-like objects. In fact you don't even need to use `call` or `bind` to accomplish this; You could attach the method to an array-like object and call it like you normally would (however I probably wouldn't recommend it).

Answer (score 1):

the apply and call do nothing and fool nothing to work on array-like elements. They simply do (work), because they expose indexes of their members.

Array methods access members by index; and if a member is of a right type for a given array method it will operate on it with the same ease it does with its own. But if the member is not of a type that can be handled by a given array method you will naturally get an error.

In earlier versions of JavaScript you could pass the object of interest as an argument to the property function of say Array object without the need of using the call or apply methods.

As in: 
`Array.split( collection );`.

Comment: What do you mean "In earlier versions of JavaScript"? If you understand how `this` is inherited you'll know that copying a method to an object is no less effective than using `.call` (regardless of the JS engine). Probably not the best way of accomplishing the task but if it works using `.call` it will work without it too. https://jsfiddle.net/0b4j158r/

Comment: Sorry, that's  still possible without the use of call, what I really meant was (because it's been quite some time since the call and apply were introduced) in fact that it was possible to use a syntax like this: `Array.split( object );` I will correct that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I understand now. I never knew the old JS was like that.

Comment: And I still don't understand why was it taken away from us!
`Aray.split(arg);` is still way more expositive than `Array.split.call(arg);` it just doesn't make more sense than the old JS traditional method.

Answer (score 1):

I think other answers described it quite well, but maybe this illustrative code could shed some light on this topic as well.  It is a tale about generic push and its artificial evil twin:

```
// create plain object
var obj = {}

// give it ability to `push` by simple assignment from some poor one-time array instance
obj.PSH = [].push
// poor array will be lost in garbage: we should have used Array.prototype instead, but nevermind

console.log(obj)
// => Object {}
// (Chrome console does not show method, but we can see it in inspection or in for-in loop:)

for(var prop in obj) console.log(prop,':',obj[prop])
// => PSH : push() { [native code] }
// ah, 'native code', how enigmatic.

// let's use it
obj.PSH('zero')
obj.PSH('one')
console.log(obj)
// => Object {0: "zero", 1: "one", length: 2}
// now we see it created numbered properties and `length` property on our object 

// what happens if we alter that `length` and call PSH after?
obj.length = 10
obj.PSH('TEN')
console.log(obj)
// => Object {0: "zero", 1: "one", 10: "TEN", length: 11}
// ah, predictable

// now we know what that native code most probably does, so we can create evil twin
function prankpush (what) {
    var where = this.length || 0
    this[where] = what      // insert that to to the last index
    this.length = where + 2 // but lets make it more interesting
}
// this time we will call it, so we will not taint out obj with another method
prankpush.call(obj,'prank2')
prankpush.call(obj,'prank3')
console.log(obj)
// => Object {0: "zero", 1: "one", 10: "TEN", 11: "prank1", 13: "prank2", length: 15}
// no 12 and length is bigger, what an evil success!

// but we could have as well do one time method assignment, call (like we did with native push in the beginning) …
obj.prankpush = prankpush
obj.prankpush('prank4')
// … and this time cover our tracks so prankpush will not be present in for-in-loop
delete obj.prankpush
console.log(obj)
// => Object {0: "zero", 1: "one", 10: "TEN", 11: "prank2", 13: "prank3", 15: "prank4", 17: "prank4", length: 19}
```